# Mock constructor of a class

Tags: mockito, junit5

I am writing test class for my java class. I am using Junit5 with Mockito.

I am using Junit5 which isnt compatible with Power Mockito so I am using Mockito only.

I have `class Emp` which have function `findSalary` like below and `EmpProfileClient` is initialized at constructor.

```
Class Emp {

......

  public void findSalary(empId) {

    ...

    TaxReturn taxReturn = new TaxReturn(EmpProfileClient);

    int value = taxReturn.apply(new TaxReturnRequest.withEmpId(empId))

                    .returnInRupee();

    ...

  }

}
```

When I am writing the test case, I mocked `EmpProfileClient`, but since we are creating `TaxReturn` in a method, How I can mock `TaxReturn.apply` so I can write the expectation to get the value as per my choice which I set in the test class?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Add a layer of indirection. Instead of calling the constructor inject a factory that produces TaxReturns.

Comment: question is how to write expectation before testing findSalary.

Comment: what you are going to test? I mean which method? You want to mock all inside `findSallary`?

Comment: or only `taxReturn.apply` invocation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock this, the `TaxReturn` class should be an injected bean in the `Emp` class. Add an injection framework (like Spring) and inject the `TaxReturn` class. In the test you write you can inject a Mock instead of the real class. See `@InjectMocks` annotation of the mockito framework.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly(you are looking for mocking `taxReturn.apply`) I'd suggest next:

**First**. Refactor your *taxReturn* instantiation(as it is would be much easier to mock method behavior in comparison for trying to mock local variable)

```
public class EmpService {

 public int findSalary(Integer empId) {
  //...
  // It's doesn't matter what the actual empProfileClient type is
  // as you mocking creation behavior anyway  
  Object empProfileClient = null;
  TaxReturn taxReturn = createClient(empProfileClient);   
  int value = taxReturn.apply(new TaxReturnRequest().withEmpId(empId))
   .returnInRupee();
  //...
  return value; // or whatever 
 }

 protected TaxReturn createClient(Object empProfileClient) {
  return new TaxReturn(empProfileClient);
 }

}
```

**Second.** Use *Mockito.spy()* in your test:

```
class EmpServiceTest {

  @Test
  void findSalary() {
    TaxReturn taxReturn = Mockito.mock(TaxReturn.class);
    // this is the main idea, here you using partial EmpService mock instance
    // part is mocked(createClient()) and other part(findSalary()) is tested
    EmpService service = Mockito.spy(EmpService.class);
    when(service.createClient(any())).thenReturn(taxReturn);
    when(taxReturn.apply(any(TaxReturnRequest.class))).thenReturn(taxReturn);
    int yourExpectedValue = 5;
    when(taxReturn.returnInRupee()).thenReturn(yourExpectedValue);
    assertEquals(yourExpectedValue, service.findSalary(0));
  }
}
```

> Keep in mind that *any(), spy(), when()* and *mock()* methods are part of Mockito API. So there is nothing hidden here